# Assign billing company to order number WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce, orders

I want to modify the order number of a WooCommerce order.
Right now it creates a number automatically like #3345

If the user fills the billing company field with 'Company' I want the order number to be 'Company#3345'.

I found this function to set a prefix for all my orders:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_order_number', 'change_woocommerce_order_number' );

function change_woocommerce_order_number( $order_id ) {
    $prefix = 'Company';
    $new_order_id = $prefix . $order_id;
    return $new_order_id;
}
```

Instead of $prefix = 'Company'; it needs to be -> $prefix = 'billing_company';

Can someone help me. This function is in my functions.php file.

If there is no option for it. Is there a function to add the SKU of the first product in cart to it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`woocommerce_order_number` pass an instance of `WC_Order` as second parameter.

Try this:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_order_number', 'change_woocommerce_order_number', 10, 2 );

function change_woocommerce_order_number( $order_id, $order ) {
    $new_order_id = $order->get_billing_company() . $order_id;
    return $new_order_id;
}
```